# Fix uninitialized constant error of existing migrations for deleted table (including model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I have a cars table which was created a year ago and needs to be renamed to vehicles table now.

Car table migration

```
class AddDataToCarsModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    # some cars are missing their created timestamp
    Car.where(created_at: nil).each do |car|
      date = Time.zone.now
      car.update_attribute(:created_at, date)
    end
  end
end
```

Vehicle table renaming migration

```
class RenameCarsToVehicles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    rename_table :cars, :vehicles
  end
end
```

However, when dropping the current db and running the migration I get `uninitialized constant AddDataToCarsModel::Car` error as I have already removed the cars model as a part of it.
What is a best practice for these situations? Is it worth running into old migration that was create a year ago and update it?
How can we handle these situations?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: when the `Car` model was removed, any references to Car should have been handled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a fix of your migration you could change your `AddDataToCarsModel` migration into this:

```
class AddDataToCarsModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]

  class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'cars'
  end

  def change
    # some cars are missing their created timestamp
    Car.where(created_at: nil).each do |car|
      date = Time.zone.now
      car.update_attribute(:created_at, date)
    end
  end
end
```

So you can use `Cars` model only in this migration. And this will not break anything into your app lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to check if a class `Car` exists.

```
class AddDataToCarsModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    if begin
         Object.const_get(Car.to_s).is_a?(Class)
       rescue StandardError
         false
       end
      # some cars are missing their created timestamp
      # All the car objects can be updated at once using this.
      Car.where(created_at: nil).update_all(created_at: Time.current)
    end
  end
end
```